# Configure cmake to work with homebrew libraries instead system-provided libraries

Tags: cmake

I find myself going against the grain configuring cmake paths with ccmake over and over again as with every change of for ex. compiler some of my library paths get lost.

In particular paths to (unlinked) lapack, lapacke, gsl get either lost or set to system defaults instead the ones I've installed with brew.

There has to be a way to tell cmake to "ignore" system libraries and instead look in homebrew paths (say. /opt/homebrew/lib, /opt/homebrew/include etc.).

I'd prefer not to link those libraries as this is not recommend and I'm not experienced in switching environments.

[EDIT] MRE:

```
git clone https://gitlab.physik.uni-muenchen.de/AG-Scrinzi/tRecX.git
cd tRecX
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Parallel
make -j 8
```

I add the following to .bash_profile/.zshrc:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib" 
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/include" 
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib/pkgconfig /opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"
```

then I try:

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/homebrew -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=NEVER -DCMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE=NEVER -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH=FALSE -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH=FALSE -DMPI_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/mpicxx -DMPI_C_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/mpicc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-11 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most common solution is to just set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `/opt/homebrew`. CMake will then look preferentially in `/opt/homebrew` for everything. Since you're on Apple, you might need to set `CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK` and `CMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE` to `LAST` or `NEVER`, too.

You can skip the standard platform search paths by setting `CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH` to `FALSE` at the command line, in a preset, or in a toolchain file. You might also wish to disable looking at the `PATH` environment variable by setting `CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` to `FALSE`.

Finally, if you're in a cross-compiling scenario or toolchain file, you can change the *definition* of the system directories by setting `CMAKE_SYSROOT`. Note that the sysroot will have to contain the language runtime libraries (e.g. glibc) and will be passed to the `--sysroot` flag (or equivalent). Just be aware of those effects, too.

All of this is documented here:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK.html#variable:CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE.html#variable:CMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE

---

The following `homebrew.cmake` toolchain file worked for me:

```makefile
set(HOMEBREW_PREFIX "/usr/local"
    CACHE PATH "Path to Homebrew installation")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/bin/gcc-11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/bin/g++-11")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
    "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}"
    # These libraries are keg-only and not loaded into
    # the root prefix by default (to avoid clashes).
    "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/lapack"
    "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/openblas"
    "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11"
)

list(TRANSFORM CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH APPEND "/include"
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")

set(CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE NEVER)

set(CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH FALSE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH FALSE)
```

I built with the following commands:

```
$ ls 
tRecX  homebrew.cmake
$ cmake -G Ninja -S tRecX -B tRecX-build \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$PWD/homebrew.cmake \
    -DCBLAS=/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/libblas.dylib \
    -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup" \
    -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup" \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Parallel

[ ... output clipped ... ]

Boost found -- full functionality

Build "Parallel" with C++ flags  -D_USE_BOOST_ -O3  -pthread  -D_USE_FFTW_, return to default by -UCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE

            Compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++-11, change by -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=[path_to_complier]

-- Linking to libraries Boost::system;Boost::filesystem;/usr/local/lib/libfftw3.dylib;/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/11/libgfortran.dylib;alglib;/usr/local/lib/libarpack.dylib;Boost::system;Boost::filesystem;/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/liblapacke.dylib;/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/libblas.dylib;/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/liblapack.dylib;/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/libblas.dylib;m
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/alexreinking/Development/tRecX-build
$ cmake --build tRecX-build
```

I had to set `CBLAS` manually because `libblas.dylib` provides the OpenBLAS CBLAS interface, but the build system specifically looks for a library named `libcblas`. There's no other option in this case.

The code and build have issues with its linking model and dependencies. I was able to paper over these by setting `-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup`. However, note that this will just defer linker errors to runtime and might impose a large startup cost.

If you can make commits to the project, I would store these settings in a [preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html), maybe name it `homebrew-parallel` or something:

```
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$PWD/homebrew.cmake \
    -DCBLAS=/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/libblas.dylib \
    -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup" \
    -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup" \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Parallel
```

Then you could just run `cmake --preset=homebrew-parallel`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've run `cmake .  -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/homebrew -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=NEVER -DCMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE=NEVER -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH=FALSE -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH=FALSE` yet it still uses Xcode gcc compiler rather than homebrew gcc by default...

Comment: Ok, maybe it'd be better to try the other way around - is there a way to temporarily link all keg-only libraries from brew?

Comment: @Ranza - it doesn't look like you set the compiler you want to use... You'll need to set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`. Also, Xcode "gcc" isn't actually gcc, it's a symbolic link to Apple's clang. You'll need the full path to the Homebrew compilers.

Comment: Right, so I've tried: `cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/homebrew -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=NEVER -DCMAKE_FIND_APPBUNDLE=NEVER -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH=FALSE -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH=FALSE -DMPI_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/mpicxx -DMPI_C_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/mpicc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-11 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11`

Comment: and also added `export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/lapack/lib/pkgconfig /opt/homebrew/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"` before to zshrc and restarted the shell but it still doesn't find BLAS, CBLAS, LAPACK nor LAPACKE

Comment: Can you give an MRE so I can reproduce this locally? I think the right solution for you will be to create a toolchain file.

Comment: Sure, just added.

Comment: @Ranza - I got pretty far, but get linker errors at the end. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Lapack related? I'm stuck at missing symbols like "_LAPACKE_zgbrfs" too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234133/discussion-between-alex-reinking-and-ranza).

Comment: @Ranza - please see the chat link above

Comment: thinking how to make old cmakefiles work that don't rely on find_package, and or use find_library instead and don't work on Apple M1 with homebrew. Would find_package be a preferable approach over cmake prefix path ?