# Cmake find_package does not work with Doxygen

Tags: cmake, package, homebrew, conan

### Objective

I am trying to have CMake find Doxygen on a bunch of different systems and configurations:

- Online documentation is generated on Ubuntu
- Local tests and development is done on Macos
- Doxygen can be installed system-wide, through brew or through conan depending on the use case

### Problem

I struggle finding a uniform approach that does not involve a lot of OS-specific operations. I am vaguely tempted to glue together the 3 following approaches, but I am still surprised/concerned/unsure a more elegant solution does not exist.

#### Sub-solution 1

What I have presently works only for system-wide installations:

```
find_package(Doxygen
             REQUIRED dot
             OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS mscgen dia)

if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)

  # doxygen settings can be set here, prefixed with "DOXYGEN_"
  # ...

  # this target will only be built if specifically asked to.
  # run "make docs" to create the doxygen documentation
  doxygen_add_docs(
    docs
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generate API-documents."
  )
else (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  message([WARNING] " Doxygen need to be installed to generate the doxygen documentation")
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

#### Sub-solution 2:

I am aware I can try to access Conan-installed executable through `CONAN_BIN_DIRS_DOXYGEN/doxygen`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68934644/10360134)

#### Sub-solution 3:

I am also aware I can try to locate Homebrew installations as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68105857/10360134).

Comment: Finding packages in the "build" context, where ``tool_requires`` like Doxygen should be, is a bit challenging, but can be done with ``CMakeDeps``: Using the ``build_context_activated`` (https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html#build-context-activated), can force the creation of doxygen-config.cmake files. And the path to the generated ``doxygen-config.cmake`` file can be also automated with ``CMakeToolchain`` generator

Comment: Can I use `build_context_activated` with a `conanfile.txt` or have I to use a `conanfile.py` for  this?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to move to ``conanfile.py``, but it will be very basic, it doesn't need to contain the whole thing, just ``settings``, ``requires`` and the ``generate()`` method

Comment: Thank you @drodri! I could do what I wanted thanks to you! I will post the answer based on your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @drodri comments, the following `conan/conanfile.py` achieves the desired result for my header-only library:

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeDeps

class MyConan(ConanFile):
    name = "mylib"
    version = "0.1"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "arch", "build_type"
    exports_sources = "include/*", "CMakeLists.txt", "test/*", "cmake/*", "docs/*"
    no_copy_source = True
    generators = "cmake", "CMakeToolchain", "CMakeDeps"
    requires = "boost/[>=1.78.0]", "gdal/[>=3.4.3]"
    tool_requires = "cmake/3.24.2", "doxygen/1.9.4"

    def generate(self):
        cmake = CMakeDeps(self)
        # generate the config files for the tool require
        cmake.build_context_activated = ["doxygen/1.9.4"]
        cmake.generate()

    def build(self): # this is not building a library, just tests
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        cmake.test(output_on_failure=True)

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h")

    def package_id(self):
        self.info.clear()
```

It can be called with `conan install conan/conanfile.py --build=missing --install-folder=build -pr:b=conan/profiles/clang_13 -pr:h=conan/profiles/clang_13`